# How to make ExternalProject_Add default build not invoke install

Tags: installation, cmake, external-project

I am adding CMake build support to a make based project. I am using ExternalProject_Add for this. EVerything up to INSTALL_COMMAND works fine. But I want the default target (I guess all target) to not include install. Basically I want default target to only include up to build and then install to be a separate command. How can I achieve that? Leaving INSTALL_COMMAND as "" and adding a

```
ExternalProject_Add()
install(CODE "execute_process(\"echo Hello\")")
```

Didnt seem to help. The echo never ran.

Comment: *The echo never ran.* Did you build the install target of your project, e.g by running `cmake --build <build-dir> --target install`? `install(...)` steps are only run when installing, which seems to be exactly what you wanted to have ("Basically I want default target to only include up to build and then install to be a separate command.")

Comment: I also just realized that the syntax of your `execute_process` call is wrong. It needs to be `install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND echo Hello)")`